# how to make an element visible on hover?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to make a child of a parent div visible on hover. I want the text to fade in with an ease when one of the glyph-icons is hovered over to reveal the text that corresponds to it also. I want to make each menu item slide out with an ease when hovered over but i have no idea how to set up eases within css3.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html{
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(36,36,36,1.00);
 background-image:url(../img/bg.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#BoarLogo{
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 opacity: 0.7;
 z-index: -1;
}

#MainNav{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 7em;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 margin: 20px;
 
}
#MainNav ul{
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px;;
}

.placeholder{
 padding: 10px;
 height: 80px;
 width: 250px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative

}

.placeholder a img{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
}

.placeholder a span{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: left;
}

.placeholder:hover{
}

.linkItem:hover{
 padding-left: 20px;
}

.linkItem{
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}

.linkItem img{
 
}

.linkItem span {
 
 
}

#BoarLogo img{
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
/* handles css for smart phones.*/
 #BoarLogo {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
 }
 
 #MainNav{
  
     
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Wild Boar Homepage</title>
<meta name="description" content="Wild Boar Cafe Restaurant is a coffeehouse in Fort Collins Colorado. ">
<meta name="keywords" content="Coffee, Fort Collins, Colorado, Restaurant, Latte, Mocha, Food,  ">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <nav id="MainNav">
  <ul>
   <li class="placeholder"><a class="linkItem" href="#"><img style="height: 80px; width: 80px;" alt="Home icon" src="img/home.png"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class="placeholder"><a class="linkItem" href="#"><img alt="About icon" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;" src="img/info.png"><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class="placeholder"><a class="linkItem" href="#"><img alt="Menu icon" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;" src="img/menu.png"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
   <li class="placeholder"><a class="linkItem" href="#"><img alt="Catering icon" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;" src="img/Catering_icon (1).png"><span>Catering</span></a></li>
   <li class="placeholder"><a class="linkItem" href="#"><img alt="Contact icon" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;" src="img/contact.png"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div id="BoarLogo"><img alt="Wild Boar Cage Logo" src="img/BoarLogo.png" /></div><!-- End main background logo-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: hide <ul> on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710054/css-hide-ul-on-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the fade in/fade out effect you can set the opacity of the text to 0 and change it to 1 when the parent is hovered.

You'll also need to define the transition:

`transition: all 1s ease;`

- all - means that every property change will have the transition effect
- 1s - the transition will take 1 second
- ease - the transition timing function

If you want a different effect on hover out, you'll have to use JavaScript.

I made some changes in your HTML, use classes to style your elements, don't use inline style (`style="height: 80px; width: 80px;"`), it makes your code more readable and easier to maintain.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

html {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(36, 36, 36, 1.00);
  background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#BoarLogo {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: -1;
}

#MainNav {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 7em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 20px;
}

#MainNav ul {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  ;
}

.placeholder {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.placeholder a img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.placeholder a span {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.placeholder:hover {}

.linkItem:hover {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.linkItem {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.linkItem img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.linkItem span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#BoarLogo img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.linkItem:hover span{
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* handles css for smart phones.*/
  #BoarLogo {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
  }
  #MainNav {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Wild Boar Homepage</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Wild Boar Cafe Restaurant is a coffeehouse in Fort Collins Colorado. ">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Coffee, Fort Collins, Colorado, Restaurant, Latte, Mocha, Food,  ">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="MainNav">
    <ul>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <a class="linkItem" href="#">
          <img alt="Home icon" src="img/home.png">
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <a class="linkItem" href="#">
          <img alt="About icon" src="img/info.png">
          <span>About</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <a class="linkItem" href="#">
          <img alt="Menu icon" src="img/menu.png">
          <span>Menu</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <a class="linkItem" href="#">
          <img alt="Catering icon" src="img/Catering_icon (1).png">
          <span>Catering</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <a class="linkItem" href="#">
          <img alt="Contact icon" src="img/contact.png">
          <span>Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="BoarLogo"><img alt="Wild Boar Cage Logo" src="img/BoarLogo.png" /></div>
  <!-- End main background logo-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow that is so cool thank you so much! I will definitely consider taking that in-line code out I second your thoughts on it being harder to read and understand (thinking back on it I think I put that in because the images were not responsive to the div that they were in)

Answer (score 0):

the css selector should be:

```
.linkItem img:hover > span{
    /* your animation */
}
```